# SOLR fq (filter query not working)

Tags: solr

It appears that the fq seems to  be not  working for dismax. I am using solr 2.2

my query is http//mysolrserver:8983/solr/fd=modelid=810 ...

My solr config is default and I get the values if I set q=modelId:810 and not fq=modelId:810

Any ideas ?, Is there any filter in solrconfig that stops fq ?

Comment: whats Solr 2.2 ? and whats the field defination for modelID field ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wanna appy filter query over all docs in your index, here is syntax for that:

```
http//mysolrserver:8983/solr/select?q=*:*&fq=modelid:810
```

or in your solrconfig.xml, you can specify your own request handler, with q.alt set to *:*

```
<requestHandler name="/custom" class="solr.SearchHandler">
<lst name="defaults">
<str name="echoParams">explicit</str>
<str name="defType">dismax</str>
<str name="qf">
title^5.0 description^1.0 keywords^3.0
</str>
<str name="q.alt">*:*</str>
<str name="rows">10</str>
<str name="fl">*,score</str>
</lst>
</requestHandler>
```

and then your query will be:

```
http//mysolrserver:8983/solr/custom?fq=modelid:810
```